# Strike-Down Markdown text between two symols

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to emulate the strike-through markdown from GitHub in python and I managed to do half of the job. Now there's just one problem I have: The pattern I'm using doesn't seem to replace the text containing symbols and I couldn't figure it out so I hope someone can help me

```
    text = "This is a ~~test?~~"
    match = re.findall(r"(?<![.+?])(~{2})(?!~~)(.+?)(?<!~~)\1(?![.+?])", text) # Finds all the text between ~~ symbols
    if match:
        for _, m in match: # Iterates though the matches. First variable (_) containing the symbol ~ and the second one (m) contains the text I want to replace
            text = re.sub(f"~~{m}~~", "\u0336".join(m) + "\u0336", text) # Should replace ~~test?~~ with t̶e̶s̶t̶?̶ but it fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the string that you are trying to replace. In your case, `~~{m}~~` where value of `m` is `test?` the regex to be replaced becomes `~~test?~~` and here `?` has a special meaning which you aren't escaping hence the replace doesn't work properly. Just try using `re.escape(m)` instead of `m` so meta characters get escaped and are treated as literals.

Try your modified Python code,

```
import re

text = "This is a ~~test?~~"
match = re.findall(r"(?<![.+?])(~{2})(?!~~)(.+?)(?<!~~)\1(?![.+?])", text) # Finds all the text between ~~ symbols
if match:
 for _, m in match: # Iterates though the matches. First variable (_) containing the symbol ~ and the second one (m) contains the text I want to replace
  print(m)
  text = re.sub(f"~~{re.escape(m)}~~", "\u0336".join(m) + "\u0336", text) # Should replace ~~test?~~ with t̶e̶s̶t̶?̶ but it fails
  print(text)
```

This replaces like you expected and prints,

```
This is a t̶e̶s̶t̶?̶
```